# How can I link to a page that only exists with a postback?

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to link to a third-party site. On that site is a list of links, and I need to be able to link my site to destination of one of those. The problem is that the links are not going to URLs, they're using ASP.NET postbacks to display the description of each item in the list.

Here is the URL where the list is. I want to be able to link to specific entries in this list.

https://www.license.state.tx.us/ContinuingEducation/ContinuingEducationProvider.aspx?ProviderType=750

Answer (score 0):

Check for `IsPostBack` in the Page_Load, otherwise perform a `Response.Redirect` possibly? (If I'm understanding you correctly)

**EDIT**

Actually, it sounds like you want to link to a page that was generated on the value of a postback. I'm not sure you can, unless you have access to the page's code. You may try simulating the GET variables and see if the page generates the same content, otherwise it's however the author coded the page and what conditions need to be met to generate the "postback content(s)".